# location based process in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to do local push Notification (giving alert) when the user comes in particular locations(in range).is it possible to do it? any example and tutorial please?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.
Local alerts can be scheduled ahead of time, but if your app isn't running, it has no way of checking your location. This makes sense because the GPS is hard on the battery, among other reasons.

A quick glance at the reference docs for UILocalNotification confirms this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

EDIT:

Actually!
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

(scroll down to "Tracking the User’s Location")

There is a bunch of location-based background stuff you can do. I don't think you can schedule an alert based on location, but you might be able to receive location notification and fire up an alert if you're in the right area.

Comment: is it possible through -(void)locationManagerCLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegionCLRegion *)region ?

Comment: can i give alert in that method? will it be executed without opening the Application?

Comment: have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html